# Evolutional boundary condition

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider the Stokes equation in a bounded domain $\Omega$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\partial_{t}u-\Delta u+\nabla p & =0, \\
\text{div}u & =0, \\
u(0,x) & =0,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
with evolutional Dirichlet boundary condition
$$u(t,x)=\psi(t,x)\quad\text{on}\ \partial\Omega.$$

I want to know the $H^{1}$ estimate of the solution $u$, i.e. the a priori estimate of
$$\sup\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}|\nabla u|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+\int_{0}^{t}|\nabla u|_{H^{1}(\Omega)},$$
I guess the first thing to do is find an extension  $\Psi$ of the boundary data $\psi$, then consider a new unknown $u-\Psi$. But I have no idea how to determine the time derivative $\partial_{t}\Psi$.

Any references or suggestions? Thanks!